# Sql Server 2008 r2 installation error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

While installing SQL server 2008 r2 I am facing below error can any one help me how can I install.Can any one help me how can I solve this.
[image]

Comment: What happens if you click "Run the program without getting help" ?

Comment: When I take "Get help Online" It shows I required .net 3.5 framework.When I try to download it shows error as Error Code :0x800736B3.

Comment: And when you click other option? "Run the program without getting help" ?